# Monitoring ChromiumWebBrowser control initialization

Tags: winforms, cefsharp

We use the CefSharp's `ChromiumWebBrowser` control (83.4.20) in Windows Forms application.

We hook up the `IsBrowserInitializedChanged` event to know when the browser control was initialized so we can start loading our web application. Occasionally this event is not fired at all so our application will be stuck and won't load the web app.

In case the app is stuck in initializing the `ChromiumWebBrowser` control, the `WebView_IsBrowserInitializedChanged` or `WebView_LoadError` are not fired:

```cs
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.webView.IsBrowserInitializedChanged += WebView_IsBrowserInitializedChanged;
    this.webView.LoadError += WebView_LoadError;
}

private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.webView = new CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser();
    // usual WinForms initialization code from the designer
    // ...
}

private void WebView_IsBrowserInitializedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.webView.IsBrowserInitialized)
    {
        this.webView.Load(this.ApplicationUri.AbsoluteUri);
    }
}

private void WebView_LoadError(object sender, LoadErrorEventArgs e)
{
    // handle the error
    // ...
}
```

Are there any other events we can subscribe to to monitor the state of CefSharp and the browser control which would aid as in troubleshooting this situation?

Comment: Check the log file see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#log-file are you calling Cef.Initialize?  If so what values are you using?  The short answer is there is no other event and failing to initlize the browser is almost unheard of.